# Can't get my String switch statement to hit anything but default

Tags: java-8, switch-statement

I am trying to use a switch statement to pass a LinkedHashMap to the correct class constructor for a school project(I just added the rest of the code).

The code reads takes in a txt file and based off the first word in the text sends the hash map.

I can't seem to get a hit on the case report I am testing. 
I have even tried just making everything into an if-else-if structure,

and that still didn't work out, 
I've tried using a private enum method to no avail.

I am at a loss here. 
I am running Java 8. 
I am open to any suggestion on optimizing the code as well.

Thanks.

```
package linkedlist;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class TextReaderGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    String rawText;

    String[] text;

    public String listType;

    private JButton fileChooserButton;
    private JLabel statusLabel;

    /**
     * Creates new form TextReaderGUI
     */
    public TextReaderGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        fileChooserButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        statusLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        fileChooserButton.setText("File Chooser");
        fileChooserButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                fileChooserButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        statusLabel.setText("Status: ");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout
                .createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(14, 14, 14).addComponent(fileChooserButton))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(36, 36, 36).addComponent(statusLabel)))
                .addContainerGap(264, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(16, 16, 16).addComponent(fileChooserButton)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(statusLabel).addContainerGap(221, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void fileChooserButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

                rawText = "";
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                StringBuilder stringb = new StringBuilder();
                String s;
                while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringb.append(s);
                    stringb.append("\n"); // this makes sure that java sees when a new line has started
                }
                rawText = stringb.toString();
                statusLabel.setText("Status: " + file.getName());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            statusLabel.setText("Status" + e);
        }

        text = rawText.split("\n"); // creating a string array split at each line break

        Map<String, String> lines = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) { // this sets the first word of the line = key
            String[] currentLine = text[i].split("\\s+"); // splits the words in the current line to an array
            if (i == 0) {

                listType = currentLine[0].replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // determines listType to pass

            }
            if (currentLine.length > 1 && i > 0) {
                lines.put(currentLine[0] + " " + i, currentLine[1]); // if two words exist on a line
                                                                        // the first is the key second is the value
            } else if (currentLine.length == 1 && i > 0) { // keeps list type out of key values
                lines.put(currentLine[0] + " " + i, ""); // " " + i is used to ensure that each command is unique key
            }
        }
        lines.keySet().forEach((name) -> {// Testing to see if document was correctly placed into the HashMap
            String key = name;
            String value = lines.get(name);
            System.out.println(key + " " + value + "\n");
        });

        System.out.println(listType); // testing to see if list type was correctly stored

        switch (listType) {
        case "stack":
            Stack stack = new Stack((LinkedHashMap) lines);
            break;
        case "queue":
            Queue queue = new Queue((LinkedHashMap) lines);
            break;
        case "dll":
            Dll dll = new Dll((LinkedHashMap) lines);
            break;
        case "sll":
            System.out.println("almost there");
            Sll sll = new Sll((LinkedHashMap) lines);
            break;
        case "cll":
            Cll cll = new Cll((LinkedHashMap) lines);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("something went wrong here");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but it should be noted that your switch doesn't appear to actually do anything. It creates local variables, that go immediately out of scope.

Comment: What is the problem? Your code prints `"almost there"`. It "hits" `sll` as it should.

Comment: Make sure the actual string you're using doesn't have some whitespace in it somewhere. This MCVE looks fine afaik.

Comment: I just updated the code to the complete class code, Showing where I set the string. If i just manually set it, the switch does work, which i didn't try before. But i need to set the String based off the first word in a user selected text file.

Comment: where is your test data anyway? Can you show me the contents of data?

Comment: working on it right now.

Comment: whats the best way to provide the text file that I am using?

Comment: Just a small remark, your code to print the map contents can be simplified to `lines.forEach((key,value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value + "\n"));`.

Comment: You are reading a file line by line, joining all of them to a giant string, the splitting it up again to an array, just to process them one by one. Why don’t you process the line right after reading in the intended way, without all these obsolete steps?

Comment: I re made the text file, sorry I never got it up loaded anywhere and the program correctly save listFile without adding a space in front of the word.  Im not sure why but before I could not trim() or .replaceall(""\\s+, ""); on the string to get rid of the space.

Comment: Holger, I made the foreach adjustment. And I am not to familiar with how the read line works. I do need to make sure that a line break is added in so I can correctly parse the line into the LinkedHashMap